# [SSRS][SharePoint] How to avoid display the elements when counting on a group by tablix?

Tags: reporting-services, count

New to SSRS, we asked me to create a simple report on SSRS, linked to a Sharepoint List.

The Report consists of a tablix with two columns: Client and the number of orders they passed.
The first column is only containing the sharepoint field "Client Name", and the report generate automatically a list of Clients based on the content of the Sharepoint List. The Column is also used as a group by to the Tablix, to group the results by Client Name.

My second column is an expression :

```
=Count(Fields!ID.Value, "Client")
```

The column is working nearly accordingly to my willing : the report displays the number of orders by client in the list, but... When a client has more than one order, the count is displayed the same number of times.

How can i prevent that? I tried a Running Value solution, or only count.. But if the results are not the right one, the same problem is occuring : The report tablix have as much rows than elements list.

Picture for helping, because my english is far for perfect.
[Image of the multiples rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkhLm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `client column` in group expression in Details section. Check below screen shot, It will help you.

[image]

Comment: Hi ! It worked perfectly fine ! Can I ask why the result is different than just the regular drag & drop field to the column group? So this feature doesn't group the details and child group?

Thanks again, it's a life savior for me !